# How to change jQuery hoverIntent plugin instance settings on-the-fly?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, hoverintent

I am using [jQuery hoverIntent plugin](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) like this:

```
$('#box').hoverIntent({ over:function_a, out:function_b, interval:0 });
```

However I want to change setting on-the-fly of this instance within `function_a` to set interval to 500. Can this be achieved and how ?

Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hoverIntent plugin add two custom attributes to every DOM element it's assigned to

For example: `<div id="box">` became `<div id="box" hoverIntent_t="" hoverIntent_s="">`

Now:

- hoverIntent_t is the polling interval timer, or the mouseOut timer.
- hoverIntent_s stores the state to prevent unmatched function calls.

So you can directly change the internal state of *#box* like this:

```
$("#box").attr("hoverIntent_t", "500");
```